# How do you disable electric tripwires?

Tags: bioshock

I know that explosions and running through them will disable tripwires, but the former involves rare ammunition and the latter reduces health.

Is there any other way to disable them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's several ways to disable electric tripwires.  I've listed them in what I find easiest to hardest.

- Just run through them
- Pick up some debris lying nearby and hold it in front of you as you walk through it.  The object will trigger the wire safely.
- Same thing, but throw the debris into the wire.
- Use telekinesis to yank the bolts out of the wall.
- Shoot the bolts
- Use a grenade to set off an explosion near them
- Just run through them, but with Electric Flesh equipped.  (Electric Flesh reduces or eliminates electrical damage)
- Use Telekinesis to yank the bolts out of the wall and then hurl them into unsuspecting splicers, electrocuting them for epic lolz.

Other plasmids may work on them as well, but a combination of telekinesis, the debris-carry method, and just plain not noticing them (oops!) is what got me through.

Comment: You can also use the electro-plasmid for disabling them (maybe that counts as shooting at the bolts).

Comment: After considering all these options, I choose to run through them :)